# How to add dependency in react-native plugin for iOS?

Tags: java, swift, xcode, react-native, plugins

I'm created plugin using this command
**npx create-react-native-library react-native-randomness** 
I write code for ios is it in <root_dir>/ios and add pod dependencies there.  
But when I build the project I got this error. 
** BUILD FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'react-native-awesome-module' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure) 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is this the full error message?

Comment: Yes this is full message. Also I have noticed that on pressing jump to definition of library , incorrect file is opening.